# Unity: Skipping through GameObjects with different KeyPress

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to have one gameObject active. At the moment with "space" I can count from 1 to 12 and one single gameObject is active. Now I want it the other way round from 12-1 with "Esc" for example...

Thank you for your help!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ToggleTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objects;
    public int objCount = 0;


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            objCount += 1;
            objects[objCount].SetActive(true);
            objects[objCount - 1].SetActive(false);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following work for you? You might want to erase the `else` if you want to negate the effects on simultaneous pressing of `space` and `escape`

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && objCount < 11)
    {
        objCount += 1;
        objects[objCount].SetActive(true);
        objects[objCount - 1].SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) && objCount > 0) 
    {
        objCount -= 1;
        objects[objCount].SetActive(true);
        objects[objCount + 1].SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was very easy and it works so well! Thank you very much!!